# Linux - importing "." or "::" within the root PATH

Tags: linux, unix, path, root

I am looking into Miscellaneous Config and I am researching roots PATH.
I am told that "." and "::" should be removed from the path as it is a security threat.
I have the following example output of the PATH command: /usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java7_64/jre/bin:/usr/java7_64/bin:/opt/IBM/xlC/13.1.3/bin

If this output was to contain "::" or "." how would it look like withinin the above path so I can have an idea on how it will be structured as I am not sure.

Really appreciate the help on this one.

Comment: What's the deal with `::`? I'm not aware that this has any special meaning in paths.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: When a command is searched, the PATH is examined from left to right. When a command can be found in two dirs,  mention the one you need first. When you don't trust a dir, don't add it into your path or as the last directory to be examined.